# Obtaining the state of a tkinter entry widget

Tags: python, function, tkinter, widget, state

Is there a way to obtain the state current state of an entry widget? I thought I could with a .winfo method, but that doesn't seem to be the case? Trying to create a function/button that acts differently based on the state of an entry widget... So far, no luck... any ideas?

The Entry and Button widgets:

```
    self.contact_phone = tk.Entry(contact_frame, font='arial 10 bold', relief='flat', bg='grey60', textvariable=self.var3, state='readonly', readonlybackground='grey60')
    self.contact_phone.place(anchor='nw', y=50)

    self.change_phone = tk.Button(contact_frame, text='Change', font='arial 10 bold', bd=2, bg='grey80', command=self.changephone)
    self.change_phone.place(anchor='nw', y=48, x=180)
```

the proposed function(left out the open/write to file stuff for brevity):

```
def changephone(self):
    if #the state of the widget is readonly:
        '''config the widget to allow entry'''
        self.contact_phone.config(state='normal', relief='sunken', bg='white', bd=2)
        '''change the text on the button to reflect the other functionality'''
        self.change_phone.config(text='Apply')
    elif #the state of the widget is normal:
        '''get the new contents and write it to a file'''
        newnumber = self.contact_phone.get()
        #open a file and write the new number to it...
        '''return the widget and button to their previous states'''
        self.contact_phone.config(state='readonly', relief='sunken', readonlybackground='grey60')
        self.change_phone.config(text='Change')
```

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: read up on the `cget` method.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Totally forgot that even existed...

Answer (score 1):

Solution: `widget["state"]`

````
from tkinter import Tk, Entry

app = Tk()
e = Entry(app,state="readonly")
e.pack()

print(e["state"])

app.mainloop()
```
````